# Cloude9 workspace MongoDb connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud9-ide

I am working in c9.io ide with nodejs project. In that I am trying to connect to mongodb database. I have already installed mongodb module.

In command prompt I can able to run mongodb commands like

`use database`
`db.inventory.find()`

To take advantage of Mongodb in application, I have written below code in server.js file

```
//MongoDB
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://" + process.env.IP + ":" + process.env.PORT + "/[dbname]", function (err, db) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Mongo Connected.");
    } else {
        console.log("Mongo not Connectd");
    }
});
```

But after running Server.js file, I get output as

`Mongo not Connected`

I have outputed `err` variable -- And it prints

```
{ [MongoError: server 0.0.0.0:8080 sockets closed]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'server 0.0.0.0:8080 sockets closed' }
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: [Do you have MongoDB process running and listening for connections?](https://docs.c9.io/docs/setting-up-mongodb)

Comment: Yes I have followed all the steps -- Also created data directory in workspace. But still not connecting :(

Comment: Can you print the `err` argument and edit your question?

Comment: added err details -- Its saying 'server 0.0.0.0:8080 sockets closed'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got help for Cloude 9 Support, The reply is as follows

```
You should change the line that says:

`MongoClient.connect("mongodb://" + process.env.IP + ":" + process.env.PORT + "/[dbname]", function (err, db){ `

You are connecting to `process.env.PORT`, but that is not the port for mongodb.
Simply use the default connection url here, it should work: 

`mongodb://localhost:27017/[dbname]`
```

changing `mongodb://" + process.env.IP + ":" + process.env.PORT + "/[dbname]`  to `mongodb://localhost:27017/[dbname]` resolved the issue